# NPM Start: INVALID VALUES error for SCRIPTS (windows)

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, package.json, npm-scripts, npm-start

Having issues trying to NPM START a react app using IntelliJ on Windows machine. The app was built on a Mac and seems to start on a MAC without issues. It is maybe to do with the formatting of the script variables when using Windows machine?

## **DEBUG LOG:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle recorderApp@1.0.0~prestart: recorderApp@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle recorderApp@1.0.0~start: recorderApp@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle recorderApp@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle recorderApp@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\brendan\cst-Compozed\call-recorder\client\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;c:\oracle\product\12.1.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\oracle\product\12.1.0.2_32b\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\brendan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\brendan\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Apache Maven\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin;;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\brendan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\brendan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\brendan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Gradle\gradle-5.2.1\bin;C:\Users\brendan\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.5\bin;;C:\Users\brendan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\brendan\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Apache Maven\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin;;C:\Users\brendan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
9 verbose lifecycle recorderApp@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\brendan\cst-Compozed\call-recorder\client
10 silly lifecycle recorderApp@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'webpack --mode none; NODE_ENV=local webpack-dev-server --host localhost --port 3000' ]
11 silly lifecycle recorderApp@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle recorderApp@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: recorderApp@1.0.0 start: `webpack --mode none; NODE_ENV=local webpack-dev-server --host localhost --port 3000`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid recorderApp@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\brendan\cst-Compozed\call-recorder\client
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v10.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error recorderApp@1.0.0 start: `webpack --mode none; NODE_ENV=local webpack-dev-server --host localhost --port 3000`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the recorderApp@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

## **PACKAGE.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "recorderApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "eslint": "eslint src/**/**/**/*.js --fix && eslint src/**/**/*.js --fix",
    "start": "webpack --mode none; NODE_ENV=local webpack-dev-server --host localhost --port 3000",
    "webpack": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode development --config webpack.config.js"
  },
```

Comment: For cross-platform compatibility you'll need to utilize [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to handle setting the environment variable, i.e. the `NODE_ENV=local` part in your `start` script. Also you _may_ need to replace the semi-colon (`;`) with a space and ampersand (`&`).

Comment: @RobC Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for failed on windows is set NODE_ENV variables across the script, `*inx` and `windows` are not compatible.

`cross-env` can solve this problem. check the docs [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env)

usage example

```
start: "cross-env NODE_ENV=production"
```